# Casting string to literal bytes

Tags: c++, string, casting, char

Let's say I have a string that is actually bytecode

```
"90B482"
```

I need to convert this into an array of char in the following style:

```
unsigned char converted = { '\x90', '\xB4', '\x82' };
```

This is going to be consistently calculating, so I need an efficient way to do this, but the only way I have been able to come up with in terms of solving this is writing a massive parsing function

Comment: A simple loop, a few comparisons, and a few arithmetical operations, does not make for a "massive parsing function". Various C and C++ libraries have been doing this kind of conversion, efficiently, for decades now. It helps if, you know, understand the ASCII character set, and how to trivially convert hexadecimal ASCII characters.

Comment: Have you tried `atoi` and then using right shifts? You could find better solutions, like Sam pointed out correctly, however this is a rather easy solution.